# How mention friends via put_wall_post with Koala

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, sinatra, koala

I make mention of my friends using the Koala, Ruby with Sinatra.
I reviewed the documentation and found nothing about it.
Remembering that, I do not want to send a message to a friend of mine, but I want mention him with me.
My code:

```
@graph  = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
@app  =  @graph.get_object(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"])

if session[:access_token]
   @graph.put_wall_post("title temp", {
   "name" => "name temp",
   "link" => "http://www.site-temp.com/",
   "description" => "I Know temp Description",
   "picture" => "http://site-temp.com/image.jpg"
   })      
end
```

I added this picture to understand better what I want:

[image]

So if someone has, any idea how to do this, let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Tags" option [here in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts).